# Visual Studio 2015 borra mis archivos al momento de guardar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Estoy trabajando en una pagina web en visual studio 2015 y al momento de guardar por un ejemplo un archivo html me lo borra del proyecto y no me aparece en el explorador de soluciones y si vuelvo a crear el un archivo con el mismo nombre me lo reaparece

> Eso sucede solo cuando guardo y me lo borra del explorador de soluciones que puede estar sucediendo?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir algo más de información? ¿De dónde lo borra: del "Solution explorer" o borrar el fichero físico?

Comment: Del solution explorer independientemiente en carpeta se encuentre el archivo

Comment: ¿Tienes Windows 10? Aquí hablan de un posible fallo tras actualización de Windows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47208157/files-disappear-from-vs-2015-solution-after-saving